# Button in the iOS simulator isn't working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have created a simple app and I am a beginner in iOS development.
When I click on the buttons, they don't work. Even they don't blink as a button usually blinks when clicked.

Here is the code I have written:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func showMessage() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"Hi!", message: "This is your first app", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func guitar() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hi!", message: "You have just clicked the guitar button!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func car() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hi!", message: "You have just clicked the car button!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func football() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hi!", message: "You have just clicked the football button!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the UI of the app:

[image: Screenshot of the simulator]

I have created four buttons. After creating the buttons, I have created four functions in the viewcontroller.swift file. After that, I just linked the functions just like in the screenshot here:

[image]

I am following Appcoda beginner iOS 10 Swift 3 book.

Comment: Did you do anything "out of the ordinary" when you created your buttons? Are they standard `UIButton` class, or a subclass?

Comment: HI, I just dragged and dropped the buttons from the list. Then I just gave them the name, added background colors etc.

Comment: Hi, the issue is solved. There was some problem in the Xcode. I just restarted my MacBook and it started working. Thanks for your response.